# What is the meaning of X[:,:,:,i] in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this subcode in Python and I cannot understand what it is or what it does, especially this statement:

```
X[:,:,:,i]
```

The subcode is:

```
train_dict = sio.loadmat(train_location)
X = np.asarray(train_dict['X'])

X_train = []
for i in range(X.shape[3]):
    X_train.append(X[:,:,:,i])
X_train = np.asarray(X_train)

Y_train = train_dict['y']
for i in range(len(Y_train)):
    if Y_train[i]%10 == 0:
        Y_train[i] = 0
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train,10)
return (X_train,Y_train)
```

Comment: It looks like X is a 4D array, and so you are cutting out a 3D slice and appending it to X_train.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I don't think "subcode" is a real word. I do appreciate your attempt to coin it though.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks to u

Comment: @MadPhysicist This is a subcode in tensorflow code for load a data, but I am a new in python and I think I did not search good to explain it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called array slicing. As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ mentioned, `x` is a 4D array and `X[:,:,:,i]` gets one specific 3D array slice of it.

Maybe an example with fewer dimensions can help.

```
matrix = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
```

In this case `matrix` is a bidimensional array:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

Therefore `matrix[:, 1]` will result in a smaller slice of `matrix`:

```
array([1, 3])
```

In original code `matrix[:,:,:, 1]` each of the first `:` mean something like "all elements in this dimension".

Have a look at how array slicing works in numpy [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/02.02-The-Basics-Of-NumPy-Arrays.ipynb#Array-Slicing:-Accessing-Subarrays).